# Android App crashes on Android M ,O with error on login A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x343a2944 in tid 17938

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, permissions

I have been working on project which is done by another developer and i just joined to his position and the app is full of bugs and firstly the app works on android N and doesn't work on M,L,O..and when i click on login it just shows this in logcat and i am stuck with this!can anyone guide me!

LOGCAT:

```
08/04 16:06:59: Launching app
$ adb push E:\Android\Workspace Noushad\Android MyScrap modified\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.myscrap
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/com.myscrap"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.myscrap
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "com.myscrap/com.myscrap.SplashActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.myscrap.test | com.myscrap
Connecting to com.myscrap
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
W/ActivityThread: Application com.myscrap is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/art: Debugger is active
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1486)
I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
I/MultiDex: Installing application
I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
V/FA: Collection enabled
V/FA: App package, google app id: com.myscrap, 1:605563401441:android:803a298082ff852a
I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11910
I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
        adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.myscrap
D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
V/FA: Persisting first open: 1533384960767
W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.myscrap/shared_prefs/com.google.android.gms.measurement.prefs.xml.bak
I/GAv4: Google Analytics 11.9.10 is starting up. To enable debug logging on a device run:
          adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
          adb logcat -s GAv4
W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.myscrap/shared_prefs/com.google.android.gms.analytics.prefs.xml.bak
W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.myscrap/shared_prefs/com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:settings.xml.bak
I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics 2.3.17.dev
W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.myscrap/shared_prefs/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core:com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.xml.bak
D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.myscrap/shared_prefs/com.crashlytics.prefs.xml.bak
E/isMyServiceRunning: false
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
V/FA: onActivityCreated
W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.myscrap/shared_prefs/com.device.UUID.xml.bak
D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4438298 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
D/MessageService :: onStartCommand
D/Socket:: null
E/User: null
D/Service:: Started
D/OkHttp: --> POST https://myscrap.com/android/myScrapMobileSecurity http/1.1 (75-byte body)
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.myscrap/shared_prefs/TwitterAdvertisingInfoPreferences.xml.bak
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@be8577c time:49908198
V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{4e84db3 token=android.os.BinderProxy@be8577c {com.myscrap/com.myscrap.SplashActivity}} show : true
W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.myscrap/shared_prefs/com.google.android.gms.appid.xml.bak
V/FA: Setting useService: true
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 281191657
V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 609
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 281191813
I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SplashActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3799261320423055874}]
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 5
D/FirebaseInstanceId: topic sync succeeded
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.myscrap/shared_prefs/io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.xml.bak
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK https://myscrap.com/android/myScrapMobileSecurity (2648ms, unknown-length body)
D/updateDeviceDetails: Successfully Inserted
D/API_KEY: 33008af526cf92db
D/API_KEY_STATUS: 1
W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.myscrap/shared_prefs/com.myscrap.xml.bak
D/updateDeviceDetails: onCompleted
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 281196607
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@be8577c time:49912966
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.myscrap time:49914924
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 281198635
D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=2028, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SplashActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3799261320423055874}]
V/FA: onActivityCreated
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 281198845
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{173d8b0 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=SplashActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=3799261320423055874, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=LoginActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3799261320423055875}]
D/OkHttp: --> POST https://myscrap.com/android/myScrapMobileSecurity http/1.1 (75-byte body)
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@ec2b662 time:49915313
D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK https://myscrap.com/android/myScrapMobileSecurity (2367ms, unknown-length body)
D/updateDeviceDetails: Successfully Inserted
D/API_KEY: 33008af526cf92db
D/API_KEY_STATUS: 1
D/updateDeviceDetails: onCompleted
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
V/FA: Session started, time: 281206819
D/FA: Logging event (FE): session_start(_s), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=LoginActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3799261320423055875}]
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/API_KEY: guestuser007143
D/MyPreferenceManager: User is stored in shared preferences. Guest User, 
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.myscrap time:49923872
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 8728
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 281207573
D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=8728, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=LoginActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3799261320423055875}]
W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.myscrap/shared_prefs/myscrap_gcm.xml.bak
V/FA: onActivityCreated
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/API_KEY: guestuser007143
E/markerList: 0
E/Markers Download: started 1533384977229
D/calling: update
D/API_KEY: guestuser007143
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x343a2944 in tid 17938 (com.myscrap)
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 281207822
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have resolved same issue by following code.
Add android:vmSafeMode="false" in application tag in Manifest file.
Your application tag should looks like:**

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:vmSafeMode="false">

 </application>
```

**Hope this will help you.**